# How to delay time in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to make a delay before redirect to this code `return redirect('home')`.

I have imported `time` and used `time.sleep(5)` but it seems it doesn't work with `django`!

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Where did you use the `time.sleep(5)`?

Comment: before             return redirect('home')

Comment: You mean between `login(request, user)` and the return statement? It is probably intercepted by an exception caused by the `login` function and never reached the `time.sleep`.

Comment: yes between them, so what should I do to delay before return redirect?

Comment: You can put the `time.sleep(5)` before `login(request, user)` or outside of the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

you can delay returning response like this:

```
def login_page(request):
    time.sleep(5)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
```